# Why do I see "undeclared identifier" in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I recently started a book knowing nothing about Macs or Xcode called *Beginning iOS 5  Development*. I'm in chapter 4 and either I made a mistake or they made a typo. I cannot figure it out, so here's the problem:

```
- (IBAction)textFieldDoneEditing:(id)sender {
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
}


-(IBAction)backgroundTap:(id)sender {
    [nameField resignFirstResponder];
    [numberField resignFirstResponder];
}

- (IBAction)sliderChanged:(id)sender {
    UISlider *slider = (UISlider *)sender;
    int progressAsInt = (int)roundf(slider.value);
    sliderLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", progressAsInt];
}

@end
```

They told me to add the bold text after the `sliderChanged` method. Now Xcode is saying "use of undeclared identifier" so I can't run the app to preview on the iOS simulator. BTW, it says the problem is the `sliderLabel.text`.

Comment: Where do you declare sliderLabel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your header file has an `IBOutlet UILabel *sliderLabel` in the interface declaration (and that it is connected to a label in your view).

Comment: I am really not sure how to do this... should i control drag the label for the slider and create an outlet? and what name should i give it

Answer (score 0):

Second paragraph of page 98 describes how to name the label "sliderLabel". The label itself was created in the last paragraph of page 96. The critical thing here is to inspect the property of the label in assistant editor, and change the "Name" field of the label widget to "sliderLabel".

Comment: please could you elaborate for those users without the text?

Comment: A more precise answer might be - undeclared identifier means that "sliderLabel" has not been defined as a field or property in your project that is visible to this implementation.  Check the book, its probably right, but also when the compiler says a variable is undefined, learn what that means.